# MySQL - Revoke all permissions for three columns on a group of tables

Tags: mysql, security

I am trying to revoke access to certain columns for pretty much every user on my DB on a group of tables. I understand [Revoke permissions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/revoke.html) but from what I can see, that's on the table/schema level.  How would I do something like:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES on schema.table.column from 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

Comment: The way you do this is by writing views that provide access to the columns you want to allow, and revoking all permissions on the table itself. If you give someone permission to use the view, it can access the columns it needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no simple way to write a view that just excludes certain columns. You have to enumerate all the columns you want to allow.

Answer (score 0):

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html:

> The privileges that a user holds for a database, table, column, or routine are formed additively as the logical OR of the account privileges at each of the privilege levels, including the global level. It is not possible to deny a privilege granted at a higher level by absence of that privilege at a lower level.

This means you could grant privileges to individual named columns, but you can't grant privilege to the whole table and then try to revoke privilege for certain columns. The privilege on the whole table still applies to that user.

Another way of thinking about this is that you can't revoke a privilege at a finer level of granularity than you have granted.

A workaround is to grant not at the table level, but at the column level only. For example, if you want the user to access col1, col2, col6, but not other columns:

```
GRANT SELECT (col1, col2, col6) ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

If the list of columns you want to grant access is long, so be it. It may be inconvenient, but that's the way it works.

Another workaround is to grant no privileges on that table, but make a view as Barmar suggests in the comments. The view's definer has privileges on the base table, but the view only exposes certain columns. Then you grant access to the view to your users.